# Xcode 4.6 - object model - set current model

Tags: xcode, core-data

I created a new .xcdatamodel as my earlier version wasn't recognised because of the entity changes.
How do I set the .xcdatamodel to current.

I am not able to set the "version Core data model " to current.

Answer (score 0):

In Xcode, select the `xcdatamodeld` on the left. In the file inspector on the right you will now have entries for all of your model versions under

```
Versioned Core Data Model -> Current
```

Just select the one you want.

Comment: Xcode does not always show the list under the file inspector. Other solutions have been posted